# Problems loading stylesheet and permalinks after rebooting

Tags: permalinks, css, apache, linux

I am using Ubuntu Server 10.04.02 LTS to host my WordPress, which version is 2.9.2. The problem is, after rebooting the server and loading my homepage of WordPress, the style of my blog was just missing, and all permalinks could not be loaded, even /wp-admin! However, after restarting apache2 with sudo service apache2 restart, they just all came back!

Could someone please help me troubleshoot the problem? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

### Updated: Solution

Replace `<VitualHost my.domain.com:80>` with `<VirtualHost *:80>` in `apache2/sites-available/virtualhostfile` then reload apache2. That's it :)

Comment: This question needs modifying and moving over to either Ask Ubuntu or Server Faults

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your not starting Apache properly either way this sounds like a server issue not Wordpress

Comment: Yes indeed, the problem was virtualhost directive of Apache2.

Comment: how about hitting that check mark to the left